# Submit every similarly named elements of a list of vectors to a function in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

Below, I'm wondering how to use BASE R function `quantile()` separately *across* elements in `L` that are named `EFL` and `ESL`?

***Note:** this is a toy example, `L` could contain any number of similarly named elements.*

```
foo <- function(X) {
  X <- as.matrix(X)
  tab <- table(row(X), factor(X, levels = sort(unique(as.vector(X)))))
  w <- diag(ncol(tab))
  rosum <- rowSums(tab)
  obs_oc <- tab * (t(w %*% t(tab)) - 1)
  obs_c <- colSums(obs_oc)
  max_oc <- tab * (rosum - 1)
  max_c <- colSums(max_oc)
  SA <- obs_c / max_c
  h <- names(SA)
  h[is.na(h)] <- "NA"
  setNames(SA, h)
}  

DAT <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/X.csv", row.names = 1)
L <- replicate(50, foo(DAT[sample(1:nrow(DAT), replace = TRUE),]), simplify = FALSE)

# How to use `quantile()` separately across all similarly named elements (e.g., EFL, ESL) in `L[[i]]` i = 1,... 5

# quantile(all EFL elements across `L`)
# quantile(all ESL elements across `L`)
```

Comment: How about this? `sapply(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, L)), quantile)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous solution I used `do.call` to `rbind` each list into a matrix and array and then calculate the quantile over each data.frame row.

```
sapply(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, L)), quantile)
```

However, when there is a missing row, it does not take that into account. To accurately get the rows you need to fill the missing rows. I used `data.table`'s `rbindlist` (you could also use `plyr::rbind.fill`) with `fill=TRUE` to fill the missing values. It requires each to be a data.frame/table/list, so I converted each to a data.frame, but before doing so you need to transpose (`t()`) the data so that the rows line up to each element. It could be written in a single line, but it's easier read what is happening in multiple lines.

```
L2 = lapply(L, function(x){as.data.frame(t(x))})
df = data.table::rbindlist(L2, fill=TRUE) # or plyr::rbind.fill(L2)
sapply(df, quantile, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `purrr::transpose`:

```
Lt <- purrr::tranpose(L)
quantile(unlist(Lt$EFL),.8)
quantile(unlist(Lt$ESL),.8)
```

Comment: Possibly you have been downvoted because your code throws error. `Error: 'tranpose' is not an exported object from 'namespace:purrr'`

Comment: @reza, I don't know, [transpose belongs to purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/transpose.html). Perhaps better to stick to base R...

Comment: I see a typo in your code `tranpose` instead of `transpose`.  Also, this can be modified with `purrr::transpose(L) %>% map_dbl(~ flatten_dbl(.x) %>% quantile(probs = 0.8))#
      EFL       ESL 
0.8888889 0.0000000`

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I was too fast & didn't test enough...